# Connecting to VNC Server behind Router

Tags: macos, vnc, time-capsule

Right now, I have a Mac behind a Time Capsule<sup>1</sup>, which is behind a router installed by my ISP. In System Preferences, I've enabled Remote Management, but the IP address it gives me is a local IP address. How can I set up either my VNC Server (my Mac) or my VNC Client to connect to each other?

N.B. My Mac is running Leopard, if that makes a difference.

<sup>1</sup> Equivalent to an Airport Extreme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your router (or Time Capsule, if you mean a local connection) manual for how to set up port forwarding, and forward the appropriate port (usually 5900) to the machine behind the router. Note that VNC is an insecure protocol and should not be sent over the Internet.